# Meaning of the word in the same breath

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase **in the same breath**, in the context of the following sentence

> Once the complainant opted for the refund of the amount deposited by her, later on she could not turn around and say that she be allotted a unit. She could not approbate and reprobate **in the same breath**

Answer (score 2):

*in the same breath* = *at the same time*, or *in the same transaction*. It refers to the impossibility of doing two mutually exclusive things together.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it is really just a fancy way of saying "both":

- She could not both approbate and reprobate

But normally, I would expect it to mean roughly "in the same sentence", "in the same utterance":

- You just praised and insulted me in the same breath!

It's not that common.

---

Also, note the proper pronunciation /brɛθ/.

Comment: `It's not that common.` - I wouldn't say that.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly heard, but not something you'll hear every week or even month, in my opinion.